model fine-tuning, vanishing gradient problem
I am fine-tuning a mistral-7b with Hugging Face peft and quantization. In my training loop, I am printing the gradient values for each batch which seem a bit unusual.
# Print gradients
for name, param in model_init.named_parameters():
      if param.grad is not None:
           print(f'Gradient for {name}: {param.grad.norm()}')

I am trying to understanding, why all the gradients values are 0s except for the #1 iteration (starting from 0th).
iteration 0
...
...
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.q_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.k_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.k_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.v_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.v_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0

iteration 1
...
...
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0142822265625
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 3.953125
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.1.self_attn.q_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.1.self_attn.q_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.185546875

iteration n
...
...
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.k_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.k_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.v_proj.lora_A.default.weight: 0.0
Gradient for base_model.base_model.model.model.layers.31.self_attn.v_proj.lora_B.default.weight: 0.0

Isn't this a bit unusual? Is it the vanishing gradient problem?
For context,
# custom class
class BinaryClassification(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, base_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_model = base_model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.05)
        #self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        outputs = self.base_model(x)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(outputs.logits)
        relu_output = self.relu(dropout_output[:, -1, :])
        probs = self.sigmoid(relu_output) # Apply sigmoid to logits to get probabilities
        #print('forward probs', probs)
        return probs

model_init = BinaryClassification(peft_model)

# optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model_init.parameters(), lr=0.001, eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0.001)
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.1, patience=10, verbose=True)

# Loss
def calc_loss_batch(input_batch, target_batch):
    
    output = model_init(input_batch)
    
    # Reshape target to match the shape of probs
    target_batch = target_batch.unsqueeze(1)
    
    if output.shape != target_batch.shape:
        raise Exception("Shape mismatch between input logits and target label")
    
    # Logits of last output token
    loss = criterion(output, target_batch)
    
    return loss


Try listing the values for a few more iterations from the start and the end, then we can help you better. Also which dataset are you training on? How did you load the model?
